# Is raising exceptions safe within 'before' callback of a transitions.Machine model?

Tags: python, fsm, pytransitions

I am using the [transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions) FSM library. Imagine having an application FSM using the following code:

```
from transitions import Machine

import os

class Application(object):

  states = ["idle", "data_loaded"]

  def __init__(self):
    self.data = None
    machine = Machine(model=self, states=Application.states, initial="idle")
    machine.add_transition("filename_dropped",
                           source="idle",
                           dest="data_loaded",
                           before="load_data",
                           conditions="is_valid_filename")
    self.machine = machine

  def drop_filename(self, filename):
    try:
      self.filename_dropped(filename)
    except IOError as exc:
      print "Oops: %s" % str(exc)

  def load_data(self, filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
      self.data = file.read()

  def is_valid_filename(self, filename):
    return os.path.isfile(filename)
```

It can throw an `IOError` within load_data. My question is whether it is safe to raise exceptions (either implicitly like in this example or explicitly) from within `before` callbacks? In case of an `IOError` the transition is not taking place, the state of this example remains `idle` and any `after` callbacks are not being invoked. However, I wonder whether the internal state of the machine instance might get corrupted.

Additional question: Are there any better ways to signal errors with concrete information to the application? In this very example I could use the condition to load the file, but this seems ugly and I would need some additional attribute to keep track of the error etc.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: About your additional question: What do you not like about raising Exceptions to inform your application about errors?

Comment: I am fine with raising exceptions, i was referring to the example with the file load that I don't want to open that file twice (once in the condition and once in the 'before' slot). I am probably using the condition feature here in an unusual way. It is probably meant for some things that are allowed based on some additional information.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I wonder whether the internal state of the machine instance might get corrupted.

It is fine to work with raising Exceptions in callback functions unless you plan to use the `queued` feature of transitions.

Transitions are executed in the following order:

`prepare -> conditions -> before -> on_exit -> set_state -> on_enter -> after`

If anything before `set_state` raises an Exception or a function in `conditions` does not return `True`, the transition is halted.

Your model might be in an undefined state though. If you rely on some 'clean up' or 'tear down' in `State.on_enter` or `after`:

```
from transitions import Machine
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.busy = False
    def before(self):
        self.busy = True
        raise Exception('oops')
    def after(self):
        # if state transition is done, reset busy
        self.busy = False

model = Model()
m = Machine(model, states=['A','B'], initial='A',
            transitions=[{'trigger':'go', 'source':'A', 'dest':'B',
                          'before':'before', 'after':'after'}])
try:
  model.go()
except Exception as e:
  print "Exception: %s" % e # Exception: oops
print "State: %s" % model.state # State: A
print "Model busy: %r" % model.busy # Model busy: True
```

> Are there any better ways to signal errors with concrete information to the application?

It depends on what you want to achieve. Raising Errors/Exceptions usually halts the execution of a current task. In my oppinion this is pretty much THE way to propagate issues. If you want to handle the error and represent the error as a state, I would not consider using `conditions` ugly. Valid transitions with the same `trigger` are evaluated in the order they were added. With this in mind and the use of `unless` which is negated notation for `conditions`, your code could look like this:

```
from transitions import Machine
import os


class Application(object):
  states = ["idle", "data_loaded", "filename_invalid", "data_invalid"]

  transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'filename_dropped', 'source': 'idle', 
     'dest': 'filename_invalid', 'unless': 'is_valid_filename'},
    {'trigger':'filename_dropped', 'source': 'idle',
     'dest':'data_invalid', 'unless': 'is_valid_data'},
    {'trigger':'filename_dropped', 'source': 'idle',
     'dest':'data_loaded'}
  ]

  def __init__(self):
    self.data = None
    machine = Machine(model=self, states=Application.states,
                      transitions=Application.transitions, initial="idle")
    self.machine = machine

  def drop_filename(self, filename):
      self.filename_dropped(filename)
      if self.is_data_loaded():
          print "Data loaded"

  # renamed load_data
  def is_valid_data(self, filename):
    try:
      with open(filename) as file:
        self.data = file.read()
    except IOError as exc:
      print "File loading error: %s" % str(exc)
      return False
    return True

  def is_valid_filename(self, filename):
    return os.path.isfile(filename)

app = Application()
app.drop_filename('test.txt')
# >>> Data loaded
print app.state
# >>> data_loaded
app.to_idle()
app.drop_filename('missing.txt')
print app.state
# >>> filename_invalid
app.to_idle()
app.drop_filename('secret.txt')
# >>> File loading error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'secret.txt'
print app.state
# >>> data_invalid
```

This will create this state machine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I now understand the conditions/unless feature much better. I was using it the wrong way, I guess. This example of the "file reader" makes much more sense.